# Matching time to system event

Tags: ubuntu, logging, electrical-power

I have a file server running Ubuntu 12.  I have recently installed noflushd to spin-down unused hard drives in an effort to extend their life.  I am noticing that every morning at the same time (07:36) the hard drives all spin-up.  I can't seem to figure out what is causing this.  Can anyone recommend a way of searching through the system logs to identify what is causing the spin-up?

I realize I can grep for the timestamp but I'm wondering if there is a quick way to grep all log files on the system.

Answer (score 0):

Scheduled tasks in Debian/Ubuntu are stored under `/etc/cron.*` and controlled by `/etc/crontab`. The line triggering the daily tasks must be defined similar to this:

`25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )`

Look inside the `/etc/cron.daily` directory to find out what is being triggered.